# PHP - Not getting transactional info when Return to merchant from paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I have a paypal button on my page, where in I need to receive payment. I downloaded the code from  [HERE](https://www.phpzag.com/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-php/) , all works fine it takes me to paypal page I can send money adn recieve it too(I am using sandbox account).
However when transaction is complete and click on `Return to merchant` It shows me `Payment has failed`. I have `$_GET['variable']` to access different transaction infos.
Heres my code for `success.php' page :

```
<?php
include_once("db_connect.php");
/*include './db_config.php';*/
//Store transaction information into database from PayPal
$item_number = $_GET['item_number']; 
$txn_id = $_GET['tx'];
$payment_gross = $_GET['amt'];
$currency_code = $_GET['cc'];
$payment_status = $_GET['st'];
echo $txn_id;
//Get product price to store into database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$item_number'";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". 
mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset);
if(!empty($txn_id) && $payment_gross == $row['price']){
  //Insert tansaction data into the database
  mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO payments(item_number,txn_id,payment_gross,currency_code,payment_status)VALUES('".$item_number."','".$txn_id."','".$payment_gross."','".$currency_code."','".$payment_status."')");
  $last_insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);    
?>
 <h1>Your payment has been successful.</h1>
 <h1>Your Payment ID - <?php echo $last_insert_id; ?>.</h1>
<?php
}else{
?>
 <h1>Your payment has failed.</h1>
<?php
}
?>
```

As you can see I tried to ECHO txn_id but no value.
What am I missing here.

Comment: use `echo $_REQUEST` to see what values PayPal is sending to your callback URL. This can help you to find the solution.

Comment: I put it and return just `Array` no other value

Comment: Sorry, use `print_r` instead of `echo` and do let me know what response you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue it was just some settings that needs to be done on Paypal's side and its working, refer to [THIS LINK](https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/configure-paypal-sandbox-auto-return-payment-data-transfer/)
1. I needed to change Auto Return for website payment to ON
2. Under the Payment Data Transfer to ON 
and got the results